# Fibonacci sums on a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, fibonacci, lowest-common-ancestor

Given a tree with `n` nodes (`n` can be as large as `2 * 10^5`), where each node has a cost associated with it, let us define the following functions:

- `g(u, v) = the sum of all costs on the simple path from u to v`
- `f(n) = the (n + 1)th Fibonacci number (n + 1 is not a typo)`

The problem I'm working on requires me to compute the sum of `f(g(u, v))` over all possible pairs of nodes in the tree modulo `10^9 + 7`.

As an example, let's take a tree with `3` nodes.

- without loss of generality, let's say node `1` is the root, and its children are `2` and `3`
- `costs[1] = 2, cost[2] = 1, cost[3] = 1`

---

`g(1, 1) = 2; f(2) = 2`

`g(2, 2) = 1; f(1) = 1`

`g(3, 3) = 1; f(1) = 1`

`g(1, 2) = 3; f(3) = 3`

`g(2, 1) = 3; f(3) = 3`

`g(1, 3) = 3; f(3) = 3`

`g(3, 1) = 3; f(3) = 3`

`g(2, 3) = 4; f(4) = 5`

`g(3, 2) = 4; f(4) = 5`

Summing all of the values, and taking the result modulo `10^9 + 7` gives `26` as the correct answer.

---

My attempt:

I implemented an algorithm to compute `g(u, v)`  in `O(log n)` by finding the lowest common ancestor  using a sparse table.

For the finding of the appropriate Fibonacci values, I tried two approaches, namely using exponentiation on the matrix form and another by noticing that the sequence `modulo 10^9 + 7` is cyclical.

Now comes the extremely tricky part. No matter how I do the above computations, I still end up going to up to `O(n^2)` pairs when calculating the sum of all possible `f(g(u, v))`. I mean there's the obvious improvement of only going up to `n * (n - 1) / 2` pairs but that's still quadratic.

What am I missing? I've been at it for several hours, but I can't see a way to get that sum without actually producing a quadratic algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

To know how many times the cost of a node X is to be included in the total sum, we divide the other nodes into 3 (or more) groups:

- the subtree A connected to the left of X
- the subtree B connected to the right of X
- (subtrees C, D...   if the tree is not binary)
- all other nodes Y, connected through X's parent

When two nodes belong to different groups, their simple path goes through X. So the number of simple paths that go through X is:

> #Y + #A × (N - #A) + #B × (N - #B)

So by counting the total number of nodes N, and the size of the subtrees under X, you can calculate how many times the cost of node X should be included in the total sum. Do this for every node and you have the total cost.

---

The code for this could be straightforward. I'll assume that the total number of nodes N is known, and that you can add properties to the nodes (both of these assumptions simplify the algorithm, but it can be done without them).

We'll add a *child_count* to store the number of descendants of the node, and a *path_count* to store the number of simple paths that the node is part of; both are initialised to zero.

For each node, starting from the root:

- If not all children have been visited, go to an unvisited child.
- If all children have been visited (or node is leaf):

  - Increment *child_count*.
  - Increase *path_count* with N - *child_count*.
  - Add this node's *path_count* × *cost* to the total cost.
  - If the current node is the root, we're done; otherwise:

    - Increase the parent node's *child_count* with this node's *child_count*.
    - Increase the parent node's *path_count* with this node's *child_count* × (N - *child_count*).
    - Go to the parent node.

Comment: Really cool idea, this seems like it can be done in one fell swoop using depth first search, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Can you include some pseudocode?

Comment: @user43389 Thanks. I added some pseudo-code; it's quite straightforward and should be no problem to implement, unless you can't add properties to the nodes; then you'd need to use additional storage, like a second tree with identical structure.

Comment: Are you sure this approach fits the problem? Namely, the cumulative cost of each node doesn't actually provide an insight on how to compute `f(g(u, v))`, where `g(u, v)` has the aforementioned definition. Your method allows us to compute the sum of all `g(u, v)` but this doesn't solve the problem at hand, as we need to sum over `f(g(u, v))`.

Comment: @user43389 I concentrated on one part of the task, that I thought was most problematic; it's true that it doesn't solve the hole problem as is; there's probably an additional mathematical trick to make the step to the Fibonacci numbers, but I can't think of it right away. Feel free to unaccept the answer if you think it's not as helpful as you first thought.

Comment: Also, do you consider X,X to be a valid pair? Because I didn't, so you'd have to add every node's cost (twice?) to get the right total in that case.

Comment: Yes, I consider (X, X) to be a valid pair. I don't intend to unaccept the answer, it shows a lot of useful effort. It's just that I struggled for a while in order to adapt it to the full problem and I thought I missed something in your explanation.

Comment: @user43389 I assume the choice of Fibonacci to complicate the problem is not just random; the fact that a Fibonacci number is the sum of previous Fibonacci numbers can probably be leveraged in some way.

Answer (score -1):

The below algorithm's running time is O(n^3).

Tree is a strongly connected graph without loops. So when we want to get all possible pairs' costs, we are trying to find the shortest paths for all pairs. Thus, we can use Dijkstra's idea and dynamic programming approach for this problem (I took it from Weiss's book). Then we apply Fibonacci function to the cost, assuming that we already have a table to look up.

- Dijkstra's idea: We start from the root and search all simple paths from the root to all other nodes and then do that for other vertices on the graph.
- Dynamic programming approach: We use a 2D matrix D[][] to represent the lowest path/cost (They could be used exchangeably.) between node i and node j. Initially, D[i][i] is already set. If node i and node j is parent/child, D[i][j] = g(i, j), which is the cost between them. If node k is on the path which has lower cost for node i and node j, we can update the D[i][j], i.e., D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j] if D[i][j] < D[i][k] + D[k][j] else D[i][j].

When done, we check D[][] matrix and apply Fibonacci function to each cell and add them up, and also apply modulo operation.

Comment: This is far too slow, as you can see from my post, my algorithm runs in `O(n ^2 * log n)` which is still not fast enough. An `O(n log n)` solution is necessary here.